# Why are operands to relative jmp/call instructions treated as absolute by NASM / ndisasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, disassembly

According to "x86 Instruction Set Reference", `EB cb` opcode corresponds to
`JMP rel8` mnemonic which, in turn, corresponds to "Jump short, relative, displacement relative to next instruction."
From this, one could conclude (at least I would) that operand of JMP represents an offset relative to IP for both an opcode and mnemonic.
The code snippet below proves otherwise:

```
bits 16
nop
nop
nop
nop
nop
jmp label
label:
   nop
```

Assembled with `nasm -f bin -o test.bin test.asm` and then disassembled with `ndisasm -b 16 test.bin` it produces the following output:

```
00000000  90                nop
00000001  90                nop
00000002  90                nop
00000003  90                nop
00000004  90                nop
00000005  EB00              jmp short 0x7
00000007  90                nop
```

The second byte of the `EB00` opcode is 0 which is correct and expected as the jump target is the very next instruction (hence offset 0),
but the operand of the corresponding `jmp` mnemonic is 7, which is obviously an absolute address. I could prepend the JMP instruction
in the code above with arbitrarily many NOPs (or any other instructions), the effect of which would be such that the opcode of JMP instruction
would stay the same, but the operand of its corresponding mnemonic would increase accordingly to adjust to an absolute address of jump
target, not a relative one. Is this inconsistency something obvious, expected, intended, common to all assemblers, not only NASM? The behaviour is the same for relative CALL instruction. Is this the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, this is what it is intended as. The disassembler could say `jmp short $+2+0` which would depict the relative displacement, but it is considered more useful to decode the address to an absolute offset.

Comment: Ok, this confirms my observations and makes some sense, but there's another inconsistency: if I change default origin to, say, `0x7c00`, the resulting disassembly for `jmp label` is still `jmp short 0x7`, not `jmp 0x7c07`, so this time it's neither absolute nor relative to IP register. For `mov ax, label` this would indeed result in `mov ax, 0x7c08`, so it looks like only `jmp`, `call` and perhaps some other instructions dealing with relative addresses remain unaffected by org. I know these are beginner's questions, but I'd rather understand all this stuff than blindly memorize it.

Comment: The disassembler also uses its `-o` option to set up the origin it uses to decode IP-relative offsets: https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdocb.html#section-B.2.1 When you disassemble a block assembled with `org 7C00h` (or an `-f bin` section with `vstart=7C00h`) then you have to pass `-o 7C00h` to NDISASM as well to get the correct offsets for everything.

Comment: Fine, that makes perfect sense now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are operands to relative jmp/call instructions treated as absolute by NASM / ndisasm?

Machine code is nice for CPUs but inconvenient for humans. In machine code the operands to jmp/call instructions are relative.

Assembly language is nicer for humans (and inconvenient for CPUs). In assembly language the operands to jmp/call instructions are absolute because that's nicer for humans.

Tools (assembler, linker maybe) translate "nicer for humans" into "nicer for CPUs", including converting absolute addresses into relative offsets.

More tools (disassemblers) do the opposite and translate "nicer for CPU" into "nicer for humans", including converting relative offsets into absolute offsets.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if `org` directive comes into play? If I disassemble my original code with origin changed to `0x7c00`, ndisasm still resolves `jmp label` to `jmp short 0x7`, so now the address is neither relative to IP register nor absolute (that would be `0x7c07`). I assume it's sort of a "special case" for instructions dealing with relative addresses, but what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: @Peter: In that case, if the `org` is wrong (disassembler told something different to what assembler or linker was told) the result will be that the disassembler shows you a wrong absolute address. Of course this "shouldn't" happen - better to make things easier when people are using tools correctly (and not worry so much about what happens when people use tools wrong).

Comment: Right, I failed to realize there would be a mismatch between `org` in nasm and disasm unless explicitly adjusted. Thank you for your help.